# Shape detection in image using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, shapes, detection

I have an image with many shapes and I need to write some Matlab code which remove all the shapes except the rectangle.. Does it availabe to do it using **only** with strel,imclose and bwareaopen? if you think yes i will be very happy to hear your opinion.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Hi Devin! I can't see the image, could you include it directly into stackoverflow?

Comment: I can't do it..but try maybe this: http://imgur.com/L1KchUH

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: yes(even some days) but didn't succeed..if you have any idea to do it i will be very happy to hear

Comment: "Yes" isn't very helpful in telling us *what* you've tried. Also, I don't see why you've (seemingly) arbitrarily limited solutions to "**only** with strel,imclose and bwareaopen". Is there some particular reason for this?

Comment: if i will tell you what i have tried it will not help you because it is not working. I limited because it's some homework.

Comment: Invert the image, use a rectangle that's the same size as the one you want as a structuring element and implement an opening operation.  Reinvert the result.  Using `imclose` and/or `bwareaopen` is non-intuitive to me.

Comment: But I don't know what is the size of the rectangle, it should be work for all size and direction of the rectangle.

Comment: are you allowed to compare your input image to temporal results?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right from your comment, rectangle may have any size. I think this can be asked only if the other shapes have fixed size since you are asked to use strel, imclose and bwareaopen. To briefly explain,

**strel** function creates a structuring element with **given** size for rectangle, disk or any other shape on the picture you added.

**imclose** should be used to connect the similar shapes you give as input(basically the structuring element you should find from the strel function).

**bwareaopen** will be used to delete the objects which has less than P -given as input- pixels.

So, if the rectangle can be given in any size for this image, the other shapes should stay the same in order to be able to define them with strel function, and connect by using imclose function. In this way, you may connect them all, take inverse, remove using bwareaopen and take inverse once again to end up with rectangle.

I could not think about any other solution, hope it helps!

Comment: The other shapes could be also in a different size, the code should be generic. I have tried to do what you offered before and what happend is that the rectangle connected with some close circle.